# Avoid remove data on client when unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor, ddp

I use `observeChanges` like this

```
let handle = Message.find(query, options).observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
        self.added("message", id, getMessageFields(id));
    },
    changed: function (id) {
        self.changed("message", id, getMessageFields(id));
    },
    removed: function (id) {
        let fields = getMessageFields(id);
        if (fields != null) {
            self.changed("message", id, fields);
        } else {
            self.removed("message", id);
        }
    }
});

self.ready();
self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
});
```

And I use DDP to get data from server to Mobile (Android/iOS). But if I unsubscribe, my DDP Client callback always call `onRemoved()`. Is it possible to avoid that from server?